# CSS horizontal alignment acting weirdly with width percentages

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I know this is probably going to confuse a lot of you because it fails to make sense to me.

I am trying to create a log in page where the credentials are in the center of the page (Horizontal and Vertical center).
I've achieved that, but in my process to reach there, I encountered something that I couldn't quite understand.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="LoginWrapper">
<div class="Login">
    <div id="Username" title="Register Number">
        <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text="Username" AssociatedControlID="UserNameTextBox"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="UserNameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="LoginTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div id="Password" title="Password">
        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" Text="Password" AssociatedControlID="PasswordTextBox"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" />
        </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS classes that are responsible for the alignment

```
.LoginWrapper {
    width:1%;  //This is where it gets weird
    height:500px;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.Login {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center
}
```

As you can see, in my LoginWrapper class, I have set width: 1%. And for some reason this works. It manages to align my Login class to be at Horizontal center. I've tried to test this by zooming out from the page to the farthest and it still stays the same. Different percentages react in ways that defy my mathematics
I've tested it on every browser and the results are the same.

Can someone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of my answer:

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNTVC/)

### HTML

```
<div class="LoginWrapper center">
    <div class="Login center">
        <div id="Username" title="Register Number">
            <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text="Username" AssociatedControlID="UserNameTextBox"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserNameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="LoginTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div id="Password" title="Password">
            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" Text="Password" AssociatedControlID="PasswordTextBox"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

btw you are missing 1 `</div>`;

### CSS

```
.LoginWrapper {
    width:100%; 
    height:500px;
    /*display:table-cell; */ no need
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:gray;
}
.Login {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    background:blue;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your input on this. I like the idea that you've used. Thanks. But my question was to try and understand what exactly was happening with my code. How did that 1% manage to horizontally center align?